# Not able to update CocoaPods on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter, dart, cocoapods

flutter build ios output

```
Warning: CocoaPods minimum required version 1.9.0 or greater not installed. Skipping pod install.
  CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
  Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
  For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
```

flutter doctor

```
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    ! CocoaPods 1.8.4 out of date (1.10.0 is recommended).
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To upgrade see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.
```

sudo gem install cocoapods output

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20210313-16890-1jpy75w.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-ffi_c-dir
        --without-ffi_c-dir
        --with-ffi_c-include
        --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
        --with-ffi_c-lib
        --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
        --enable-system-libffi
        --disable-system-libffi
        --with-libffi-config
        --without-libffi-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `block in try_compile'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `with_werror'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `try_compile'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in `block in have_header'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
        from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in `have_header'
        from extconf.rb:10:in `system_libffi_usable?'
        from extconf.rb:42:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.0/gem_make.out
```

`brew install cocoapods`
is installing 1.5.2 which is not helping me. I have tried every Github, StackOverflow and Apple Answer but I'm unable to get to the bottom of this issue. I tried downgrading Xcode, Flutter and dart but still not able to solve this. Been up for the last 12 hours trying to figure this out. Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

To update Ruby run the following command:
First run:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Then:

```
rvm install ruby-2.6.0
```

To update your cocoapod Run the following command:

First run:

```
xcode-select --install

sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.0
```

In case you on M1 chip mac then run below commands as well:

```
# Install ffi
sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

# Re-install dependency
arch -x86_64 pod install
```